# List Index Out of Range Error - cannot get code to run

Tags: python

Question for you all. I'm coding an assignment for school in which I have to simulate a physical process of water flowing between three ponds, and how a pollutant dumped into pond 1 flows between the ponds. I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range".  I have tinkered around with different things all day but cannot get the error to go away.

Here is my code below: (fyi python says I have an error on line 49, 32, and 38).

```
POND_1 = [0]
POND_2 = [0]
POND_3 = [0]

# POND 1
def pond1(timeInput):
    pollutants = Inflow3(timeInput-1)-Outflow2(timeInput-1)+POND_1[timeInput-1]
    total = leakingInput*timeInput
    if total <= maximumInput:
        pollutants += leakingInput
    return pollutants

def Inflow3(timeInput):
    return 0.005*POND_3[timeInput]

def Outflow2(timeInput):
    return 0.005*POND_1[timeInput]

#POND 2
def pond2(timeInput):
    return Inflow1(timeInput-1)-Outflow3(timeInput-1)+POND_2[timeInput-1]

def Inflow1(timeInput):
    return 0.005*POND_1[timeInput]

def Outflow3(timeInput):
    return 0.005*POND_2[timeInput]

#POND 3
def pond3(timeInput):
    return Inflow2(timeInput-1)-Outflow1(timeInput-1)+POND_3[timeInput-1]

def Inflow2(timeInput):
    return 0.005*POND_2[timeInput]

def Outflow1(timeUnput):
    return 0.005*POND_3[timeInput]

# User Input
maximumInput = int(input("Please enter the maximum amount of pollutant: "))
leakingInput = float(input("Please enter the rate in which the pollutant is leaking: "))
timeInput = int(input("Please enter the amount of time you would like the simulation to run in minutes: "))

# Amount of Pollutant in Pond every hour calculation
for n in range(0, timeInput+1):
    POND_1.append(pond1(n))
    POND_2.append(pond2(n))
    POND_3.append(pond3(n))

    if n % 60 == 0:
        print("The amount of pollutant in Pond 1 is: ", POND_1[n])
        print("The amount of pollutant in Pond 2 is: ", POND_2[n])
        print("The amount of pollutant in Pond 3 is: ", POND_3[n])

    if n == timeInput:
        print("Final number of pollutants in Pond 1", POND_1[timeInput])
        print("Final number of pollutants in Pond 2", POND_2[timeInput])
        print("Final number of pollutants in Pond 3", POND_3[timeInput])
```

Comment: Please add the full trackback (Error message) to your post.

Comment: Is this the full code? lines 32, 38 and 49 are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo:

```
def Outflow1(timeUnput):
```

has to be:

```
def Outflow1(timeInput):
```

Comment: Nooo, don't vote me up! Now i have a repdigit in my reputation.... whatever,  liquor for everyone! ;-)

Comment: Thank you! The most difficult errors to find/correct are the ones that are typos.

Comment: typos are always the first thing I check when I get an exception.